# Jquery Selecting form element generated by Extjs

Tags: jquery, extjs4

I have a Form generated by ExtJs 4.2. i'm trying to select the form element using Jquery 1.11.1 to get the action link to use it after that. The problem is that i can select all the other elements (div, body, ...) exept 'form' element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log($('form'));
});


[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "form", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function…]
```

I think the problem is caused because the DOM object is constructed before form element is rendered.

Anyone have an idea of what can cause this problem and what can i do to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Ext does not create form element when rendering Ext.form.Panel. That's the reason you cannot find it.